# Link json object to multiple objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, hyperlink, nested

I am trying to link a json object to multiple objects.

```
    $scope.persons = [
        {"prename":"Max", "surname":"Shepherd"},
        {"prename":"Sarah", "surname":"Shepherd"}
    ];
    $scope.contracts = [
        {"contract":"liability", "payment":"8.40"},
        {"contract":"health", "payment":"48.12"}
    ];

// Save new Person
    $scope.newPerson = {};
    $scope.savePerson = function() {
        $scope.persons.push($scope.newPerson);
        $scope.newPerson = {};
    }
// Save new Contract
    $scope.newContract = {};
    $scope.saveContract = function() {
        $scope.contract.push($scope.newContract);
        $scope.newContract = {};
    }
```

How can I save a new Contract and link/nest it to 2 persons.
e.g. the liability contract should be nested to 2 persons.
The health contract should be nested only to 1 person.
But the contract should also be an own object.

The final array should propably look like this:

```
$scope.persons = [
  {
  "prename":"Max", 
  "surname":"Shepherd",
      "contracts": {
      {"contract":"liability", "payment":"8.40"}
    }
  },
  {
  "prename":"Sarah",
  "surname":"Shepherd",
    "contracts": {
      "contract":"liability", "payment":"8.40"
      "contract":"health", "payment":"48.12"
    }
  }
];

$scope.contracts = [
    {"contract":"liability", "payment":"8.40"},
    {"contract":"health", "payment":"48.12"}
];
```

Comment: can you give an example of what the final array should look like?

Comment: I added the final array.

Comment: In the $scope.saveContract function you're pushing onto an array that is undefined - $scope.contract.push(...) - This should be $scope.contracts right?

Answer (score 0):

you could add a contract id, and then link the id to each person who has the contract.

{"contract":"liability", "payment":"8.40","contractKey":"123"},
{"contract":"health", "payment":"48.12","contractKey":"321"}

$scope.persons = [
  {
  "prename":"Max", 
  "surname":"Shepherd",
      "contracts": {
      "123",
      "321"
    }
  },
  {
  "prename":"Sarah",
  "surname":"Shepherd",
    "contracts": {
      "123"
    }
  }
];

Then you would need a function to search for the correct contracts

```
function findContractForAllPeople(){
   angular.forEach($persons,function(key,values){
        angular.forEach(values,function(DataKey,val){
          angular.forEach($contracts,function(contractKey,contractDetails) 

           if(DataKey === "contracts"){
             if($scope.contracts.contractKey === val){
               $scope.finalArray[prename] = {"contracts":contractDetails }
           }
        })
      })
   })
}
```

this will create an object that will look like this

```
{
Max:{
"contracts":{"contract":"liability", "payment":"8.40","contractKey":"123"},
{"contract":"health", "payment":"48.12","contractKey":"321"}}
},
Sarah:{
{"contract":"liability", "payment":"8.40","contractKey":"123"}
}
```